# Why go func in Go function needs waitgroup to exit correctly?

Tags: multithreading, go, synchronization, race-condition, goroutine

Sry this title might be misleading. Actually the full code is here below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Button struct {
    Clicked *sync.Cond
}

func main() {
    button := Button{
        Clicked: sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{}),
    }
    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            wg.Done()
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }

    var clickRegistered sync.WaitGroup
    clickRegistered.Add(2)

    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("maximizing window")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("displaying dialog")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })

    button.Clicked.Broadcast()
    clickRegistered.Wait()
}
```

When I comment some lines and run it again, it throws a fatal error `"all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"`
The subscribe function altered looks like as below:

```
subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        //var wg sync.WaitGroup
        //wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            //wg.Done()
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        //wg.Wait()
    }
```

What makes me confused is that whether `go func` is executed before the outer `subscribe` function returns. In my thought, the `go func` will run as a daemon though the outer function has returned, so the `wg` variable is unnecessary. But it shows I'm totally wrong. So if the `go func` has the possibility of not being scheduled, does it mean that we must use the `sync.WaitGroup` in every function or code block to make sure the goroutine is scheduled to be executed before the function or code block returns?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `c.Wait()` in either call is not guaranteed to run before `button.Clicked.Broadcast()`; and even your original code's use of `WaitGroup` does not guarantees it either (since it is the `c.Wait()` part, not the spawn of the goroutine that is important)

modified subscribe:

```
subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, subWG *sync.WaitGroup, fn func()) {
        go func() {
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            subWG.Done() // [2]
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
    }
```

code of waiting:

```
subWG.Done()
button.Clicked.L.Lock()
button.Clicked.L.Unlock()
```

This is based on the observation that `[2]` can only happen either at the beginning or after the all previous goroutines that execute `[2]` is holding on `c.Wait`, due to the locker they shared. So `subWG.Wait()`, meaning that `2` (or number of the subscriptions) `[2]` is executed, it is only possible that one goroutine is not holding on `c.Wait`, which can be solved by asking for the locker to `Lock` another time.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6mjUEcn3ec5

Comment: in your first snippet : if you move `c.L.Lock() // [1]` right after `wg.Wait()`, you won't hit a deadlock.

Comment: @leafbebop The use of `button.Clicked.L.Lock()` and `button.Clicked.L.Unlock()` seems very subtle. In my understanding, the first `Lock` call can promise all 2 subscribers are waiting on `c.Clicked`. Let's say there are n subscribers. Because the `subWG.Done` call means that all n subscribers have called `Lock`, at least n - 1 subscribers have entered the `c.Wait` call (or the `c.L.Lock` will block). So to prevent the last 1 subscriber does not enter `c.Wait`, we have to use `button.Clicked.L.Lock()` to block until the last 1 calls `c.Wait`, right?

Comment: @shengjiang Yes.

Answer (score 1):

With the `wg` waitgroup (as coded in your current group) : when the `subscribe` function returns, you *know* that the waiting goroutine has at least started its execution.

So when your main function reaches `button.Clicked.Broadcast()`, there's a good chance the two goroutines are actually waiting on their `button.Clicked.Wait()` call.

Without the `wg`, you have no guarantee that the goroutines have even started, and your code may call `button.Clicked.Broadcast()` too soon.

---

Note that your use of `wg` merely makes it less probable for the deadlock to happen, but it won't prevent it in all cases.

Try compiling your binary with `-race`, and run it in a loop (e.g from bash : `for i in {1..100}; do ./myprogram; done`), I think you will see that the same problem happens sometimes.

Comment: thanks @LeGEC I got your point. But why my use of `wg` still has problems? Do you mean when the main goroutine reaches the `button.Clicked.Broadcast()` call, the two goroutines might not have reach the `c.Wait()`? i.e. The `Broadcast` is called before the 1 or 2 goroutines is waiting on the `Clicked sync.Cond`. Am I right? Thank you for patience.

Comment: @shengjiang : yes, exactly. It looks like your are writing some test code, so I wouldn't try to build something too complicated : an easy workaround (which is *still* incomplete, but which will work well in practice), is to wait some time before calling `.Broadcast()` : `<-time.Adter(100*time.Millisecond); Button.Clicked.Broadcast()`

Comment: thank you so much! I'm indeed learning Go multithread programming. I added `time.Sleep(1*time.Second)` below the `c.L.Lock()` and the deadlock happens again as expected. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: @shengjiang : check @leafbebop's answer, he correctly suggests to acquire `cond.L.Lock()` in the main function to ensure that the other goroutines are `.Wait()`ing on that condition